# No tests were found on Android Virtual Device Emulator API 30 (UI tests)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso

I updated Android Studio till 4.1.1, i updated everything for launching emulator AVD on API 30,
but i get "No tests were found" when i'm trying to launch my UI-tests (Espresso framework) on that emulator.

In the same time i have no any problems with emulator 29 or below.

```
   --------- beginning of crash
2020-11-24 18:04:31.036 24852-24852 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    PID: 24852
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of arguments; expected 6, got 3
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.test.services.speakeasy.client.ToolConnection$ToolConnectionPostIcs.doCall(ToolConnection.java:197)
        at androidx.test.services.speakeasy.client.ToolConnection.publish(ToolConnection.java:79)
        at androidx.test.services.speakeasy.client.ToolConnection.publish(ToolConnection.java:69)
        at androidx.test.services.shellexecutor.BlockingPublish.getResult(BlockingPublish.java:74)
        at androidx.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellCommandExecutorServer.start(ShellCommandExecutorServer.java:80)
        at androidx.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellMain.main(ShellMain.java:45)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:399)
2020-11-24 18:04:31.036 24852-24852 E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad file descriptor
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:540)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.handleApplicationCrash(IActivityManager.java:5182)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$KillApplicationHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:158)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1073)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
        at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:2203)
2020-11-24 18:04:31.036 24852-24852 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24852 SIG: 9
```

Does anybody know what's the problem?
Thank a lot!

Comment: Which version of the Android test runner you use? (androidx.test:runner:x.x.x')

Comment: androidx.test:runner:1.2.0

Comment: Although i tried to update all related libraries till last stable version such as Runner 1.3.0, Rules 1.3.0, Espresso 3.3.0, Orchestrator 1.3.0, JUnit 1.1.2, but in this case i just had "Instantiating tests..." and nothing else happened.

Comment: I had similar issues after updating test runner to 1.3.0, and reverting back to the 1.2.0 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should add permission WAKE_LOCK and increase androidx test orchestrator version. Also you should check actual versions for espresso core, rules and test runner.